# Why keybd_event doesn't work in some contexts?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I want to understand why keybd_event doesn't work in some contexts. For example, it does not work in games like League of Legends or emulated games on ePSXe.

The following code:

```
Keys key = Keys.Q;

keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, 0x0001 | 0, 0);
keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, 0x0001 | 0x0002, 0);
```

Works on the game Terraria, but doesn't work on the games I mentioned before.

However, I noticed that when I try to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> on ePSXe, it works going back to the main window. It triggered the action on the emulator, but it doesn't trigger the action in the game. I am guessing the same happens on League of Legends.

Why it doesn't work exactly? Is there perhaps a way to make it work?

Comment: I believe it doesn't work on World of Warcraft as well.

Comment: Wrong scan code, it is 0x10.  Games normally protect themselves against hacks like these so multi-player games don't get ruined.

Answer (score 1):

This API is low-level; so applications do not respond to it directly. The function is called by interrupt handler. Maybe you are generating not exactly same input which you think you need for this application to respond. Also, this API is currently superseded by the function [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which I recommend to use instead of keybd_event.

Comment: I cannot understand how this answers the question.

Comment: The question is `Why keybd_event doesn't work in some contexts?` my answer says why and an alternative method that would work better.

Comment: No. SendInput and keybd_event are equivelent. They work and fail together. Do you understand why SendInput is preferred to keybd_event?